# What is the best way to deserialize objects that have interface property types using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a parent class named "Player" which is an implementation of "IPlayer". That interface/class includes a "Statistics" property of type "IStat[]". I have a corresponding "IStat" interface and "Stat" class implementation of course as well. When I attempt to deserialize, I end up with a "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'JsonSerialization.IStat'.'"

If I replace the Stats property with the type "Stat[]", that deserializes okay. I've even tried decorating my classes with "KnownType" attributes referring back to the implementation as well as done my best to configure the de/serializer with the known types and other settings I've experimented with too (enabling read only, etc.).

My player interface & class/implementation

```
    public interface IPlayer
    {
        string Name { get; }

        IStat[] Stats { get; }

    }

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(IPlayer))]
public class Player : IPlayer
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "name", Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "stats", Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public IStat[] Stats { get; set; }
}
```

My Stat interface and class/implementation

```
public interface IStat
{
    int Year { get; }

    int Wins { get; }

    int Losses { get; }

}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(IStat))]
public class Stat : IStat
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "year", Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "wins", Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int Wins { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "losses", Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int Losses { get; set; }
}
```

My deserialization method/code

```
    public static IPlayer DeserializeFromJson(string jsonSerializedObject)
    {
        var _settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();

        // I have toyed with adding known types out of desperation to no avail. 
        _settings.KnownTypes = new Type[4] { typeof(Player), typeof(IPlayer), typeof(Stat), typeof(IStat) };

        // I have experimented setting these properties to no avail.
        _settings.IgnoreExtensionDataObject = false;
        _settings.SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true;
        _settings.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 1000000;

        var _serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Player), _settings);

        using (var _stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var _writer = new StreamWriter(_stream))
        {
            _writer.Write(jsonSerializedObject);
            _writer.Flush();

            _stream.Position = 0;

            var _object = _serializer.ReadObject(_stream); // always fails here with exception
            return (Player)_object; // Never gets to this line
        }
    }
```

Some sample JSON I was feeding the deserialization method.

```
{
    "name": "Johnny Winner",
    "stats": [
        {
            "year": 1999,
            "wins": 5,
            "losses": 5
        },
        {
            "year": 2000,
            "wins": 8,
            "losses": 2
        },
        {
            "year": 2001,
            "wins": 10,
            "losses": 0
        }
    ]

}
```

I'd like to be able to deserialize classes/implementations that have interfaces as properties. But when I try to execute, I get the aforementioned

> > System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'JsonSerialization.IStat'.'

Obviously the code I put here was for demonstration purposes of the problem I'm facing only and intentionally simplistic.

Open to other creative work-arounds, but I'm hoping there's something obvious I'm just missing. My requirements due to the nature of the project I'm working on precludes me from using third party libraries (I love JSON Converter, used it for other projects but rejected from the scope for this particular project I'm on).

EDIT: I should mention, if I edit my implementation for the Player class as follows below, I achieve what I'm looking for. This is the best work-around I can find, hoping someone has something a bit more elegant if I'm missing something obvious.

```
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(IPlayer))]
    public class Player : IPlayer
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "name", Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public IStat[] Stats => StatsImplementation;

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "stats", Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public Stat[] StatsImplementation { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what happens if you remove:  `_settings.SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true;`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnB, I get the same results whether including that line (out of desperation, tried both true/false not fully understanding the behavior). Retested to confirm, same exception.